# Is it possible to photograph the aura of a person?

Tags: portrait

I have heard that auras can be recorded in photographs, but I don´t know how to do it.
Does it have to do with filters?

Comment: The type of photography that claims doing this is Kirlian photography, that was by direct contact and some electric discharge. I don't think it can be done in a portrait. But try googling the concept.

Comment: I agree with @Rafael and therefore disagree that this is a duplicate; the question is specifically about a person's aura, and a human being is not a suitable subject for Kirlian photography.

Comment: Well, probably you need a volunteer that get an electric charge all over his body Xo)

Comment: Kirlian photography aren't good for auras. Check out: [Auracam](http://www.auraphoto.com/index1.shtml). On-topic on [Paranormal proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107299/paranormal).

Answer (score 7):

There is no scientific evidence for the existence of auras. Absence of proof is not proof of absence, but since a repeatable method for capturing a person's aura would *be* that proof, we can safely say that auras do not exist, provisionally at least.

Anyone who is claiming to have photographed an aura has actually captured an image of something else. Lens flare, light leakage, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing I've seen to photographing an "aura" is a technique called [*Schlieren photography*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE9Omyg6gIE) that helps visualize differences in densities of liquids and gasses. Since living bodies emit heat, they tend to have a layer of air around them that's warmer and less dense than surrounding air. Here's an example:

[image: Schlieren photo of a person]

I've seen some web sites that explain how to capture these kinds of images yourself, like [this one](http://www.ian.org/Schlieren/HowTo.html), but I can't say I've ever tried it. In any case, I don't think that people who describe auras would generally accept that they're just simple differences in air temperature/density, so this method may not be what you're looking for.

It's also not hard to imagine ways to create a "photo" of an aura either digitally or in camera, but these fall into the category of trick photography or special effects, so they wouldn't qualify as an actual photograph of an aura.

Unfortuntely, without some solid information about what an aura *is* and how it's perceived, it's impossible to know how it could be recorded. Conversely, if we knew how to photograph a real (?) aura, we'd be well on our way to knowing what auras are.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't believe auras exist. However if they did, according to people who do believe in them, they are both invisible to most people, yet they have a colour. These two statements are contradictory, as having a colour requires something to be visible ('colour' referring to frequencies of electromagnetic radiation that exist in the visible part of the spectrum). So if they did have a colour, you wouldn't need a filter to photograph them, as cameras are designed to record visible frequencies of light. And if they are invisible, then no normal camera would be able to show them.

Comment: @drewbenn That is not about an inherent property of the aura but about the perception of it. Synesthesia happens in the head of the observer, the impression is not tied to the observed object but to the person. Color as frequency is such a property.